# Match beginning of array with another array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Let's say I have some documents that have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "letters": ["a","b","c","d"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "letters": ["a","b"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "letters": ["a"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "letters": ["x","a","b"]
  }
]
```

I want to retrieve all the documents whose `letters` array start with an n length array. For example: `["a","b"]`

So the result would be like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "letters": ["a","b","c","d"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "letters": ["a","b"]
  }
]
```

I have searched on mongo docs and stack overflow, and the only thing that's close is using `$all` operator but that's not exactly what I want.

I think it could be done by first slicing the array and then matching it with the query array, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- slice and take the first 2 of `$letters`
- check if equal with ["a" "b"]

*this is like general solution for any array, to make it work you can replace the 2 with the array size, and the `["a" "b"]` with your array

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62995e62853f039c69b0f914)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$slice": ["$letters", 2]}, ["a", "b"]]}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use array index in match query,

- check `0` index for `a` value
- check `1` index for `b` value

```
db.collection.find({
  "letters.0": "a",
  "letters.1": "b"
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AuiR5YJEKQz)